# Best WP blank(naked) template?

Tags: wordpress, themes

I like to coding few wordpress templates, and did search around that found there are few naked templates available, which i can start with.

As i am pretty new for wordpress, can you recommend the best naked template as foundation I can use?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion [Starkers](http://elliotjaystocks.com/starkers/) is the best naked/blank theme template. It is the default theme with all the styling removed.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Sandbox](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/sandbox) if you haven't yet seen it, it's pretty well organized and documented.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to actually build your own out. I work for a shop that does about 20-30 custom themes a year, with all of them having real similar functionality, but usually isn't standard / common in most themes.

Then, whenever a new theme needs to be developed, we basically copy / paste this default set of template files into a new theme folder on the WordPress install. For us, items we've included in this default setup are pre-populated header.php, footer.php, index.php, home.php, single.php, functions.php, comments.php, /images (dir), /functions (dir), style.css, /css (dir), /scripts (dir), and a handfull of other items.

Then we've also used Yahoo Grids, 960 or Google Blueprint css frames works to also speed up the css work. There's a few other items / files I'm leaving out, but should give you a general idea of what works best for us in our shop.

Answer (score 0):

DesignMag has a great article listing blank WordPress themes, in the middle of the article: http://designm.ag/resources/blank-themes-templates/

annalinnea.net's WP Blank is good, too.